# not able to access address of pointer after converting from void to int*

Tags: c

```
void *ptr;
*(int*) ptr=12;
```

After this i do not understand why does `&ptr` gives me run-time error.
while `ptr` and `*ptr` of course runs fine.

Comment: As is, `*(int*)ptr = 12;` is undefined behaviour, since you haven't allocated memory for `ptr` to point to. Probably that's what actually causes the crash.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer . I think you have the answer.

Comment: I don't want to see more UB questions today! -1 for poor phrasing and lack of research effort shown.

Comment: @H2CO3 That's easy. Shut down your computer for the night.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah, pretty much that's the only reasonable approach, quite sadly.

Comment: Shutting down the computer results in UB - there's *nothing* in the standard about that.

Comment: do some reaserch on allocating memory

Answer (score 3):

```
void *ptr;
```

Where does `ptr` point to? My bet is, to the coffee shop down the street. Or maybe even some sort of wormhole!

```
*(int*) ptr = 12;
```

So you cast a void pointer that points to who-knows-what to a pointer to int, and you then dereference that to assign it the integer 12. This will overwrite some random location in memory. If you're lucky, the program won't crash. If you're unlucky, your computer will explode.

So, to summarize and rephrase your question, you are asking us: "*Uhm, I am dereferencing a pointer I haven't initialized and points to who-knows-where. Why does my program crash?*" Do I have that right?

Answer (score 2):

First you make a pointer that points to a random address

```
void *ptr;
```

Then you try to store a value of 12 to that random address causing undefined behavior because you haven't allocated any memory for `ptr`